# Apache 403 on files moved by crontab

Tags: centos, apache-http-server

Im trying to move files with mv from user folder to web server so i can have directory listing of those files. This part is working. But files have -rwxr-xr-x+. Im not sure if this + is preventing me from download this file, cause i removed it with setfacl -bn /path and still not working

My problem is that files moved by crontab cannot be downloaded from directory listing due to 403 error. I added chmod 755 to those files and chown apache:apache, and still cant download them.

my question is is there a way to give em premission to be downloadable or can i list em directly from user folder with permission to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to permissions & ACLs, files may also have a "security label" (or security context) attached to them, most commonly by SELinux which I believe is enabled in CentOS. For example, if the file was originally created by you in /home/dawid, it'll have the security label of "user personal file" which Apache is not allowed to access, no matter where the file is moved nor what permissions it has.

`ls -lZ` will show you the current label of files and directories. As far as I know, you can use the [`restorecon`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/restorecon.8.html) command to have the system re-apply the correct label to files based on their new location – your cronjob needs to run this command every time after moving the files.

Comment: Thank you very much it solved my issue

Comment: @DawidWawrzynek If this solved your issue, you should [mark it as the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).